# Spring Boot: How to concat annotations

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-el

I have a annotation in Spring-Boot.

```
@KafkaListener (topicPattern = "mytopic1")
```

I have also a variable in my application.properties.

```
myvar = abc
```

Not I like to add myvar to my topicPattern. Is that possible??

So the resulting string used at runtime should by

```
@KafkaListener (topicPattern = "mytopic1abc")
```

Is that possible??

It should only work, if myvar is not set - thats also possible?

Comment: We can concatenate values in the `application.properties`: `foo=foo bar=bar foobar=${foo}${bar}`

Comment: I'd like to have topicPattern fix in the code. I only want myvar to be added.

Comment: [This comment (`github.com`)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/361#issuecomment-313200577) may be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Boot, you can use the *@Value* annotation along with SpEL (Spring Expression Language) to dynamically construct the topicPattern attribute of @KafkaListener at runtime based on the value of the myvar property in your application.properties file.

Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class KafkaListenerService {

    @Value("${myvar:}")
    private String myvar;

    @KafkaListener(topicPattern = "mytopic1${myvar}")
    public void listen(String message) {
        // Your Kafka listener logic here
        System.out.println("Received message: " + message);
    }
}
```

Comment: AI generated content is [currently banned](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/20153035) on Stack Overflow. Please read the [AI Policy](/help/ai-policy) for more information.